# How to convert local server to online server Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I've been developing this game for a school project. It is supposed to be online multiplayer, but this far i have online used it locally. I can figure out how to change my server code for it to be able to act as a "real" online server.

The server code:

```
// Dependencies
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var socketIO = require('socket.io');

var app = express();
var server = http.Server(app);

app.set('port', 5000);
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/static'));

// Routing
app.get('/', function(request, response)
{
  response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});



// Starts the server.
server.listen(5000, function()
{
  console.log('Starting server on port 5000');
});


// Add the WebSocket handlers
io.on('connection', function(socket)
{
  console.log('New player arrived');
});
```

Would appreciate any help greatly.

Comment: Deploy it on any server

Comment: Check this out [glitch.com](https://glitch.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the shared servers run at **port 8080**

so you may change the port then upload it into the hosting, If you just need it to be live u can use https://heroku.com/ so u can deploy it there

also here's quick option

```
npm install -g localtunnel
```

```
lt --port 8000
```

You will receive a URL, for example, https://school.localtunnel.me, that you can share with anyone for as long as your local instance of lt remains active. Any requests will be routed to your local service at the specified port

For more info: https://localtunnel.github.io/www/